# Can't find Filter class

Tags: java, filter

Sorry, this is such a dumb problem. :( I want to use [this](http://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/decorator/Filter.html) Java class:

I have the latest version of swingx added to my project's library. In the class hierarchy, I have decorator but not Filter. Actually, there are many classes missing. How can I obtain this?

Thank you!

Comment: no, swingx.decorator.* is imported...when I look at the library itself and go through the list, the class is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `org.jdesktop.swingx.decorator.Filter` does not exist anymore in lib versions ≥ 1.0 as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs/swingx/).

So there are 2 solutions:

1. Take an older library version (< 1.0)
2. Use the possibilties of the recent library version

Comment: Thank you! I will look for an alternative in the more recent version.